# Xcode doesn't symbolicate stack dump parts of the app itself

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

We recently released our iPhone app, and, as it always goes, despite a lot of testing, lots of crash reports start rolling in, which I can view in `Xcode`/`Organizer`/`Crashes`.

However, only the parts of the stack dump that come from Apple libraries, are symbolicated. Any calls to functions in our app or embedded frameworks (SQLite.swift in this case) are not symbolicated, addresses only.

I can manually symbolicate the addresses by taking the app executable out of the IPA archive in question, placing it in a directory together with the crash file, and hand it over to `atos`:

```
atos App.app/App -l <load address> -arch arm64 <unsymbolicated adresses>
```

This gives me a correct symbolication (although without line numbers), and by looking at the code, I can often fix the issues.

However, this is a tedious and time-consuming process, and I'd really love Xcode to automatically symbolicate the crashes.

How is this possible? Please let me know if you need to know about configs and stuff.